# Electric Panel / Breaker Size for Nano Brewery 2bbl Brewing Kettle

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 2bbl (make 60 gallons of beer) Brewing Kettle in my Nano Brewery.  It uses 2 4500w and 1 3000w Water Heater Elements to bring the wort to a boil.     Once to wort reaches boiling the 2 4500w elements are switched off and the 3000w has enough power to keep it at boiling.  This kettle has been in storage for many years and the original information about the electrical connections has been lost.Is a 60 amp GFCI Breaker / Panel enough to run this?   What size wire should be used within this setup.  Thanks in advance for any answers to this.

Comment: These are 240V water heater elements and your supply is a 240V split phase, correct?

Comment: 12000 w /240v =50 amps. If it takes longer than 3 hours to heat up with all 3 heaters running it would be considered a continuous load. Continuous loads should be sized at 125% for the feeder wire. #6 copper wire is good for 65 amps, If it it is a long run from the panel panel you will need to keep voltage drop in mind and the wire size may need to be increased #4 copper is good for 85 amps.